# How to use numbered lists in the post editor?

Tags: editor, list, visual-editor, formatting

I have troubles to use numbered lists in the post editor.

I want to have a numbered list where each number could have few paragraphs inside. Something like

1. List one

   some text

   paragraph two for list one
2. List two

   list text for list two

---

I had troubles to make the numbering continuous so I switched to text version and updated the code so it does what I wanted. Saved and refreshed the post page and saw exactly what I wanted. Then I go back to the post switch to visual and the post is reformatted. For example the ol tag is doubled

```
<ol style="padding-left: 30px;">
<ol style="padding-left: 30px;">
```

So the numbering is wrong, wrong indentation etc.

Any idea how I can make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this plugin:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/preserved-html-editor-markup/

It helps clear up some of the inconsistencies between the two tabs.

Comment: Well, that fixed the problem buuuuuut I hope there is some other solution available because the visual editor shows something else and 'ugly' compare to the post page that looks as desired. Isn't that strange?

Comment: Well, it doesn't work for me any more :-(